# Array filter to return a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

I have an array and I am using the filter function for arrays to check for duplicates:

```
var array = [hello, world, hello, hi, how are you];
        var uniqueArray = array.filter(function(item, pos) {
          return array.indexOf(item) == pos;
        });
    return uniqueArray.join(",");
```

Now I would like to return this unique array as a string and for some unknown reason it is failing. From the documentation, it shows that it returns an array but how can I convert that unique array to string?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: `var array = [hello, world, hello, hi, how are you];` should be `var array = ['hello', 'world', 'hello', 'hi', 'how are you'];` unless theese are the names of variables. The rest of the code works well. Btw: `.join()` and `.join(",")` are the same

Comment: @k102 specifically the `how are you` without commas would not be valid

Comment: @naomik yes, noticed it after posting a comment, thx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add quotes to your strings !

```
var array = ['hello', 'world', 'hello', 'hi', 'how are you'];
var uniqueArray = array.filter(function(item, pos) {
  return array.indexOf(item) === pos;
});
return uniqueArray.join(",");
```

Comment: If you are posting an answer, consider mentioning `===` and `join()`

Comment: Using `===` is good practice yes, but it seems like the OP is already aware of `join`

Comment: **`return`**? really? from what?

Comment: return is for the uniqueArray to be returned as a string.

Answer (score 1):

And with arrow function :

```
var arr = ['hello', 'world', 'hello', 'hi', 'hello','how are you'];
var str = arr.filter((item, pos, tab) => tab.indexOf(item) === pos).join(",");
console.log(str);
```